# Avoid "cannot find spell file" window

Tags: vimrc, spell-checking

I have `set spelllang=en_us,ru_ru` in my .vimrc, and when I enable spell check by typing `:set spell`, Vim shows me a pop-up window that says that the dictionary for the second language is not installed.

[image]

Yes, most of the time I don't have it installed, but I don't want to have this annoying pop-up window.

Is it possible to workaround this issue and simply avoid this window somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simples way to ignore this message is to globally ignore the *SpellFileMissing* autocommand:

```
:set eventignore=SpellFileMissing
```

See [:h 'eventignore](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27eventignore%27)

Answer (score 3):

`:h spell-SpellFileMissing` talks about how to handle your situation. There are basically two ways:

1. Downloading spellfiles is done with a plugin. You can simply disable that plugin.

   ```
   let loaded_spellfile_plugin = 1
   ```
2. Instead of using the plugin you can define a `SpellFileMissing` autocommand

   ```
   :au! SpellFileMissing * echo "Spell file for " . expand('<amatch>') . " not found."
   ```

Read through the help docs mentioned above for a better understanding.